# special paging requirement in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, paging

Im triing to create this logic, but i can't reach any goal.

i habe a list of Feeds.It is sometimes veri large almost 2000 entries.

now i want to create a Read function which gives me the first 40 entries and when i have read them or i have scrolled fully to the buttom the next 40 entries should be append at the buttom of the list.

My current staff:

i created a Paging with page and pagesize but the Problem is the following:
let say we have total 20 entries and a begin to request the entries:

page 1 5 items items 0 - 5 of the list (if the ar read they aren't in the list anymore!)
not i load page 2 => items 5-0 aso.. at a point it crosses itself and no items will be retrned!

has anyone an Idea how i can fix this ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use Paginator class. There is a working example on one of my repositories class:

```
<?php

namespace Fluency\Bundle\GeneralBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
use Fluency\Bundle\GeneralBundle\Entity\Country;

/**
 * CountryRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class CountryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param array $criteria
     * @param null $limit
     * @param null $start
     * @return array with this format (0 => $result, 1 => $counter)
     */
    public function findAllByCriteria($criteria = array(), $limit = null, $start = null)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c')
            ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'c')
            ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');

        if(null !== $limit)
        {
            $query->setMaxResults($limit);
        }

        if(null !== $start)
        {
            $query->setFirstResult($start);
        }

        if(!empty($criteria))
        {
            if($criteria['active'])
            {
                $query->andWhere($query->expr()->eq('c.active', $criteria['active']));
            }
        }

        $paginator = new Paginator($query);

        return array($query->getQuery()->getArrayResult(), $paginator->count());
    }
    .................
}
```